# How to register an installation remotely?

Tags: php, registration, remote-access, remote-server, user-registration

I created a website, that my users can register themselves, login and download my php application. in installer script of my application I want to send some data from their end to my server with curl and my server receives data and assign it to their account on my site. but when my server is receiving data from them, how can my server know which account they belong to, to assign it to the appropriate account?

I was thinking about asking username on installer script that they enter their username, and the username will be sent to my server with other data, so my server will know which account these data belong to, depending on the username. but I am looking for another easier way, without any need to enter the username or such info on installer script.

Is it possible? please advice. any idea? I appreciate it.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: Can you describe in short one or two possibilities to do so?